# Using OpenAPI 3.0 is there a way to link a boolean query param to a specific example

Tags: mocking, swagger, openapi

I'm mocking this in swagger.com so the frontend dudes I'm working with have a mocked api they can send queries to while I build out the endpoints.

Is it possible to filter the examples on a given endpoint by varying the parameter and if so how can you do it?

To be more specific, I want to return `#components/examples/default_vans` when `all_system_vans = false or null`

While also returning `#components/examples/all_system_vans-is-true` when `all_system_vans = true`

Below is my openapi schema.

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: "Van life"
  description: "VANS"
  version: "1.0.0"

tags:
- name: "van"
  description: "All things Van (life)."

paths:
  /vans:
    get:
      tags:
      - "van"
      summary: ""
      operationId: "getVan"
      parameters:
      - in: "query"
        name: "all_system_vans"
        description: "Default of false will get vans in ready to go, true will get all system vans." 
        required: false
        schema: 
          type: "boolean"
          default: false
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "Ok"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Vans"
              examples:
                buffer_only_vans:
                  $ref: "#/components/examples/default_vans"
                all_system_vans:
                  $ref: "#/components/examples/all_system_vans-is-true"
        "400":
          $ref: "#/components/responses/400"
        "404":
          $ref: "#/components/responses/404"

components:
  responses: 
    "400":
      description: "Invalid status value"
    "404":
      description: "Whatever you were looking for is not found."
  examples:
    default_vans:
      summary: ""
      value: {"vans": ["van_2", "van_3", "van_5", "van_7", "van_11"]}
    all_system_vans-is-true:
      summary: ""
      value: {"vans": ["van_1", "van_2", "van_3", "van_4", "van_5", "van_6", "van_7", "van_9", "van_10", "van_11"]}
      
  schemas:
    Vans:
      type: "object"
      properties: 
       vans: 
          type: "array"
          items: 
            type: "string"

externalDocs:
  description: "Find out more about Swagger"
  url: "http://swagger.io"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAPI Specification does not have any syntax to correlate response definitions to specific input values. Here's a related feature request in the OpenAPI Specification repository:
[Request/response correlation](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/2031)

But some OpenAPI mocking / service virtualication tools support such request/response correlation. For example, [ReadyAPI Virtualization](https://smartbear.com/product/ready-api/api-virtualization/) (made by the company I work for) has various [response dispatch options](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/virtualization/configure/dispatch/index.html), including sequential and random response selection as well as choosing the response based on request data.